# How to perform majority voting from a data frame with ranking criteria

Tags: r, dataframe, voting

I have the following data frame:

```
dat <- structure(list(model_name = c("Random Forest", "XGBoost", "XGBoost-reg", 
"Null model", "Plain LM", "Elastic LM", "LM-pep.charge", "LM-rf.10vip"
), RMSE = c(0.853, 0.886, 0.719, 2.41, 16.6, 0.731, 1.16, 1.03
), MAE = c(0.545, 0.708, 0.589, 1.98, 8.6, 0.588, 0.874, 0.729
), `R^2` = c(0.806, 0.865, 0.915, NA, 0.0645, 0.927, 0.8, 0.822
), ccc = c(0.89, 0.928, 0.951, 0, 0.0685, 0.945, 0.847, 0.901
)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

It looks like this:

```
  model_name      RMSE   MAE   `R^2`    ccc
  <chr>          <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Random Forest  0.853 0.545  0.806  0.89  
2 XGBoost        0.886 0.708  0.865  0.928 
3 XGBoost-reg    0.719 0.589  0.915  0.951 
4 Null model     2.41  1.98  NA      0     
5 Plain LM      16.6   8.6    0.0645 0.0685
6 Elastic LM     0.731 0.588  0.927  0.945 
7 LM-pep.charge  1.16  0.874  0.8    0.847 
8 LM-rf.10vip    1.03  0.729  0.822  0.901
```

It stores the evaluation metrics for 8 prediction models.
My goal is to select the top-performing model that consistently excels in the majority of evaluations.

By manually evaluating the metrics, I determined the top performing model this way:

```
Metrics -> Top 1
-----------------
RMSE -> XGBoost-reg 
MAE -> RF
R^2 -> Elastic LM 
CCC -> XGBoost-reg 

# Therefore, the winner is XGBoost-reg
```

It's worth noting that RMSE and MAE are error measures, with lower values indicating better performance, while R^2 and CCC are correlation measures, with higher values indicating better performance.

How can I do this with R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may either convert the data into 'long' format, do a group by 'name' and get the row with lowest value of 'value1' (after modifying the case for `R^2` and `ccc` - multiplying by -1), then get the frequency `count` and select the first row

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -model_name, values_drop_na = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(value1 = case_when(name %in% c("R^2", "ccc")~ value * -1, 
     TRUE ~ value)) %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  slice_min(n = 1, value1) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  count(model_name, sort = TRUE) %>%
  slice_head(n = 1)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 1 × 2
  model_name      n
  <chr>       <int>
1 XGBoost-reg     2
```

---

Or do the summarise to select the model_name from the numeric columns based on the min/max index and then get the `count` after converting to 'long' format

```
dat %>% 
  summarise(across(where(is.numeric), 
  ~ if(cur_column() %in% c("R^2", "ccc")) 
   model_name[which.max(.x)] else model_name[which.min(.x)])) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = NULL) %>% 
  count(value, sort = TRUE) %>%
  slice_head(n = 1)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 1 × 2
  value           n
  <chr>       <int>
1 XGBoost-reg     2
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
names(which.max(table(dat$model_name[max.col(t(replace(dat[-1], 
   is.na(dat[-1]), -Inf) * list(-1, -1, 1, 1)), 'first')])))
[1] "XGBoost-reg"
```

Comment: Thanks a million. How can I modify your code to show the "worst" model?

Comment: @littleworth I guess you may need to change the `slice_min(n = 1, value1)` to `slice_max(n = 1, value1)` in the first solution

Comment: how about `slice_head(n = 1)` ? Do I have to modify that?

Comment: @littleworth no, the `count` does `sort` based on the worst model count and so you can simply use `slice_head` with `n=1` which returns the highest count for worst model

Comment: @littleworth based on your data, I get `Plain LM ` with 3 counts as the worst one

Comment: how about reporting top-5 best?

Comment: @littleworth you may have to use `slice_head` with `n=5`